# Why when Y=-X I get negative p.d.f?

Tags: probability

Am I doing something wrong here?
Suppose we know the pdf of the random variable X  fx(x) and we wish to find the pdf of the random variable Y fy(y), where Y=-X
Then fy(y)=-fx(-y). But that means the p.d.f of Y is negative since p.d.f of X is positive.
But we can't have a negative p.d.f
What's going on here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us restrict to the case where the CDF of $X$ is differentiable.

Then its derivative serves as PDF ($F_X'=f_X$) and:

$$F_{Y}\left(y\right)=P\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} =P\left\{ X\geq-y\right\} =1-F_{X}\left(-y\right)$$
so that: $$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=F_{Y}'\left(y\right)=f_{X}\left(-y\right)$$

Equality $f_{Y}\left(y\right)=f_{X}\left(-y\right)$ holds also if $F_X$ is not differentiable.

Comment: but -y=x so I thought 1-Fx(-y)=1-Fx(x) so it's derivative is       -fx(x)= -fx(-y)

Comment: Do you agree that $F_Y(y)=1-F_X(-y)$? What is the derivative of this function?

Comment: you are right I differenciated wrt to x. my mistake